# pkcs11Interop problem with WaitForSlotEvent when reader is removed

Tags: vb.net, pkcs11interop

I set up pkcs11Interop Library as follows

```
Pkcs11Library = PkcsFactories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(PkcsFactories, pkcs11LibraryPath, AppType.MultiThreaded)
```

I then immediately use a WPF DispatcherTimer which contains the WaitForSlotEvent

```
        Private Sub CardInsertedTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Dim eventHappened As Boolean
                Dim id As ULong

                Pkcs11Library.WaitForSlotEvent(WaitType.NonBlocking, eventHappened, id)

            If eventHappened Then
                Debug.Print("CardInsertedEvent - Event - Event: " + eventHappened.ToString + "  ID: " + id.ToString)
            End If
        End Sub
```

I hope there are no surprises here. If the Slot (which is a USB smart card reader) is removed then I get a C_WaitForSlotEvent returned CKR_DEVICE_ERROR.

- Is a DispatcherTimer ok for WaitForSlotEvent?
- What should I do to avoid C_WaitForSlotEvent CKR_DEVICE_ERROR?
- Does pkcs11Interop handle the adding and removing of slots (ie.
  SmartCard Readers)?
- If pkcs11Interop does not handle adding and removing slots is polling
  the only way and what would be the best to poll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**> Is a DispatcherTimer ok for WaitForSlotEvent?**

It should be OK in general. You might also consider using `WaitForSlotEvent` in blocking mode called from a separate thread.

**> What should I do to avoid C_WaitForSlotEvent CKR_DEVICE_ERROR?**

You need to ask the vendor of your unmanaged PKCS#11 library.

AFAIK `C_WaitForSlotEvent` was designed for token/card related events not for slot/reader related events. [PKCS#11 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/blob/master/v2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf?raw=true) states that when you add or remove slot/reader you might need to reload PKCS#11 library or even restart OS:

> On some platforms, or earlier PKCS11 compliant libraries, it may be necessary to successfully call `C_Initialize` or to restart the entire system.

**> Does pkcs11Interop handle the adding and removing of slots (ie. SmartCard Readers)?**

Pkcs11Interop does nothing else but gives you access to unmanaged function `C_WaitForSlotEvent` described in [PKCS#11 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/blob/master/v2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf?raw=true).

**> If pkcs11Interop does not handle adding and removing slots is polling the only way and what would be the best to poll?**

See answer to first question.

Comment: Thank you. I am dealing with (Atos) CaedOS v5.3 - do you have any idea on avoiding the error?

Comment: Avoid removing the reader or catch that specific exception and handle it appropriately in your application.